# Are my eyes open or closed?

Tags: code-golf

You are trying to guess my emotion.

I will give you an adjective, as the input to the function/program.

Your task is to output the state of my eyes, either `O_O` for open, or `._.` for closed.

## Details

For these adjectives, you must output open eyes `O_O`

```
animated
breezy
brisk
driving
enterprising
fresh
indefatigable
industrious
snappy
spirited
sprightly
spry
stalwart
strenuous
strong
sturdy
unflagging
untiring
```

For these adjectives, you must output closed eyes `._.`

```
beat
bored
collapsing
consumed
distressed
empty
fagged
faint
fatigued
finished
jaded
wasted
worn
```

Other adjectives are undefined. You may output whatever you want for other adjectives.

## Specs

- All in lowercase. All matches regex `^[a-z]+$`.

## Scoring

This is [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). Shortest solution in bytes wins.

## Tips

There is a trick. The adjectives that correspond to closed eyes are all related to "tired". The adjectives that correspond to open eyes are all related to "active".

Comment: Why did you post 2 of pretty much the same challenges?

Comment: That one was too easy xd

Comment: Closed eyes would probably be better as `-_-`.

Comment: @KennyLau repeating the same idea in several challenges doesnt sound exciting from the second bit, try to use them as puzzles.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Minecraft Mirrored](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/53925/minecraft-mirrored)

Comment: @Mego Ummm... How?

Comment: @ericw31415 Its essentially identical to the other challenge OP just posted, which is itself a duplicate of the linked challenge.

Comment: @Mego The other one was only a duplicate because of the line length parity aspect

Comment: `Empty` doesn't follow the pattern.

Answer (score 3):

## CJam, 17 bytes

```
q1=1^'n>".O"='_1$
```

Second letters. This would have been much more fun without any "tricks" in the test cases :/

[Try it online](http://cjam.aditsu.net/#code=q1%3D1%5E'n%3E%22.O%22%3D'_1%24&input=beat).

Answer (score 2):

## JavaScript, <s>151</s> <s>123</s> <s>113</s> <s>54</s> <s>50</s> <s>47</s> 45 bytes

```
a=>["beat","bored","collapsing","consumed","distressed","empty","fagged","faint","fatigued","finished","jaded","wasted","worn"].includes(a)?"._.":"O_O"
```

Long, but it's a good start.

```
a=>/(beat|bored|collapsing|consumed|distressed|empty|fagged|faint|fatigued|finished|jaded|wasted|worn)/.test(a)?"._.":"O_O"
```

Still pretty long.

```
a=>(/beat|(bor|consum|distress|finish|jad|wast)ed|collapsing|empty|fa(gged|int|tigued)|worn/).test(a)?"._.":"O_O"
```

Eliminated some redundancy.

```
a=>/^(be|bo|c|di|en|fa|fi|j|w)\w+/.test(a)?"._.":"O_O"
```

Shorter.

```
a=>/^(a|br|dr|en|fr|i|s|u)\w+/.test(a)?"O_O":"._."
```

Switched to the other(even shorter) regex for open eyes, instead of closed ones.

```
a=>/^(a|br|dr|en|fr|i|s|u)/.test(a)?"O_O":"._."
```

Better.

```
a=>/^(a|[bdf]r|en|i|s|u)/.test(a)?"O_O":"._."
```

Answer (score 1):

## Python (2.x), <s>95</s> 94 bytes

```
import re
print('O_O','._.')[len(re.findall('^a|(br)|(dr)|(en)|(fr)|i|s|u.*',raw_input()))==0]
```

Regex! If it starts with:
`a`
`br`
`dr`
`en`
`fr`
`i`
`s`
`u`
then it is on the eyes-open list.

**EDIT:** Removed 1 byte because I didn't know how `wc` worked on `bash`. :P

Comment: Don't you mean `em` instead of `en`?

Comment: @ericw31415 No; `"enterprising"`.

Answer (score 1):

## TI-Basic, 34 bytes

```
"._.
If inString("nrpt",sub(Ans,2,1:"O-O
Ans
```

39-byte oneliner:

```
sub("._.O-O",1+3inString("nrpt",sub(Ans,2,1)),3
```

Answer (score 1):

## MATL, <s>22</s> 16 bytes

```
2)2\?'._.'}'O_O'
```

[Try it online](http://matl.tryitonline.net/#code=MikyXD8nLl8uJ30nT19PJw&input=J2ZpbmlzaGVkJw)

22 byte version, `2)'ntpr'=a?'O_O'}'._.'`.

Answer (score 0):

## [rs](https://github.com/kirbyfan64/rs), 45 bytes

```
^(.*[^t]ed|[cbwef](?![rn]).*)$/._.
[^_.]+/0_0
```

[Live demo.](http://kirbyfan64.github.io/rs/index.html?script=%5E%28.*%5B%5Et%5Ded%7C%5Bcbwef%5D%28%3F!%5Brn%5D%29.*%29%24%2F._.%0A%5B%5E_.%5D%2B%2F0_0&input=animated%0Abreezy%0Abrisk%0Adriving%0Aenterprising%0Afresh%0Aindefatigable%0Aindustrious%0Asnappy%0Aspirited%0Asprightly%0Aspry%0Astalwart%0Astrenuous%0Astrong%0Asturdy%0Aunflagging%0Auntiring%0Abeat%0Abored%0Acollapsing%0Aconsumed%0Adistressed%0Aempty%0Afagged%0Afaint%0Afatigued%0Afinished%0Ajaded%0Awasted%0Aworn)

Comment: you need four spaces to make this a code block (I can't edit because SE is bad)

Comment: @ven I made an edit; I just put an empty div tag at the end so I edited enough chars.

Comment: @AlexL. I...uhh...edited your edit. You ended up putting the whole script on one line, but it actually is *two*.

Comment: @kirbyfan64sos Whoops. Okay, thanks; I don't know anything about RS. Thanks though!

Answer (score 0):

## GameMaker Language, 72 bytes

```
a="._."if string_count(string_copy(argument0,2,1),"nrpt")a="O_O"return a
```